# Harmonic function which is zero on the boundary is zero in the domain

Tags: multivariable-calculus, harmonic-functions

> Let $u$ be harmonic ($\Delta u=0$) on the unit circle, if $u\equiv 0$ on $\partial G$ then $u\equiv0$ on $G$

We set $P=-u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}, Q=u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$

Using Green we get $$Q_x-P_y=(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})^2+u \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+u\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}+(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y})^2=(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})^2+(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y})^2$$

By green

$$\iint_{G}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})^2+(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y})^2=\oint_{\partial G}u(-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dx+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dy)=0$$

how can I an conclude that $u\equiv 0$? must it be on the unit circle?

Comment: $\iint_G|\nabla u|^2=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\nabla u=0$ in $G$ $\Rightarrow$ $u=\text{const}$ in $G$. Conclusion?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536965/using-greens-identity-to-show-that-a-harmonic-function-with-zero-boundary-value?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546633/proving-harmonic-function-is-zero?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076060/harmonic-function-if-u-0-on-omega-then-u-0-on-partial-omega?rq=1 and find another ;)